# Simulating mouse movements in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have small script in selenium to automate one website. I have also made some function to simulate the mouse movement to generate a lot of mouse moves what imitates human behaviour instead of jumping from one selector to another. I run this within new thread but after first itteration it throws selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: move target out of bounds.

Appreciate for help :)

class facebook():

```
def __init__(self, login, password, counter=0):
    self.login = login
    self.password = password
    self.browser = webdriver.Chrome("D:\selenium\chromedriver.exe")
    self.browser.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
    self.browser.set_window_size(1400,600)
    self.action = ActionChains(self.browser)

    self.thread()

def move_mouse(self):
    actions = ActionChains(self.browser)
    while True:
        delay = random.uniform(0.1,0.3)
        x = random.randint(400,900)
        y = random.randint(100,400)
        actions.move_by_offset(x,y).perform()
        print("x:"+str(x)+" y:"+str(y))
        time.sleep(2)

def thread(self):
    newThread = threading.Thread(target=self.move_mouse, daemon=True)
    newThread.start()
```

Answer (score 3):

Running this code you will eventually move to the max x,y position and try to move beyond window borders. I did some research and found that you can move to a specific position with `move_to_element_with_offset` when the element is the body tag.

Here's my proof of concept:

```
def move_mouse_to_random_position(driver):
    max_x, max_y = driver.execute_script("return [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight];")
    body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    x = random.randint(0, max_x)
    y = random.randint(0, max_y)
    actions.move_to_element_with_offset(body, x, y)
    actions.perform()
```

Comment: Related, don't work in 2023: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75818214/move-mouse-randomly-with-python-selenium-yield-selenium-common-exceptions-move